# fancyhdr gets overridden by tocloft

Tags: fancyhdr, tocloft

I wanted to change the number and distribution of dots inside my toc so I tried to change this with the tocloft package like that:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{3}
```

But doing that changes/deletes all of my fancyhdr settings I believe because after including the new package the header just simply disappears.

Here is my current preamble:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{3}

% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{titleref}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{\currenttitle}
\fancyhead[C]{Praxisarbeit}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}


%----the issue----%
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
%\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{3}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[C]{title}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman} %römische Seitenzahlen
%--------Inhaltsverzeichnis------------
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\newpage
%--------Abbildungsverzeichnis---------
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
%--------Abkürzungsverzeichnis---------
\newpage \section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
%---------------ENDE-------------------


\newpage \pagenumbering{arabic} %arabische Seitenzahlen
%--------Einleitung---------
\newpage \section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\subsection{subsection 3}

%--------Theoretischer Rahmen---------
\newpage \section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 2}

%--------Methodik---------
\newpage \section{section 3}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\subsection{subsection 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where does `\currenttitle` come from? That might not be a good choice for the headers. I doubt that tocloft is changing anything with your `fancyhdr` stuff, so I agree with @Miyase, we need a minimal self contained example that we can copy and test as is, that displays the problem, and which does not contain code that is irrelevant (such as bibliographies etc)

Comment: Also note that titleref has not beed updated in almost 20 years and it does the same as `nameref`. What exactly do you want to achive with `\fancyhead{\currenttitle}`? I would expect something like `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` here. Not `\currenttitle`.

Comment: Please read again the first comment to this question. And please note: The shown example should reproduce the problem without need to change anything. So if the commented code is needed to reproduce the problem, you should not comment it. Is `mathptmx` really needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Off-Topic: Your `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}` would add the *last* page of the table of contents to the table of contents not the first one. BTW: What benefit would you expect from such an entry? Someone, who reads this entry, already knows, where the table of contents can be found. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle IMHO this is a user mistake and the user should learn how to correct it. Helpers should not need to edit the question to see the complete code.

Comment: @cabohah I'm using ```mathptmx``` for the Times New Roman font, so I thought that might be needed

Comment: Needed *to reproduce the problem*?

Comment: Maybe? Because I don't exactly know that's producing the problem. All I know is if I comment ```\usepackage{tocloft}``` back in the header formatting is off

Comment: @Obscuritas _you_ can tell if `mathptmx` is needed before posting your question. delete it (and any other lines you can delete) and check if the problem you are asking about is shown

Comment: `Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but commenting it adds the header to page I and II as well, and that's what I wanted

Comment: Is `\tocloftpagestyle{fancy}` or `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` what you want? See the `tocloft` manual for more information.

Comment: `tocloft` sets the page style for the first page of the listing to `plain`. Either do as @cabohah said or use `fancyhdr` to adapt the `plain` style, if you want some variation from `fancy` here. (It doesn't sound as if you do want that, but in case you do.)